Computing the second Chern character of $\text{End}(E)$
Let $E \to M$ be a complex vector bundle with a hermitian metric $h$ and $\nabla$ a connection on $E$. Its quite straightforward to conclude that $c_1(\text{End}(E)) = 0$. I'm trying to verify the equation
$$
\text{ch}_2(\text{End}(E),\widetilde{\nabla}) = \text{tr}\left(\frac{i}{2\pi} F_{\widetilde{\nabla}} \wedge \overline{\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}F_{\widetilde{\nabla}}\right)}^T\right),
$$
but I can't get to this. By definition
$$
\text{ch}_2(\text{End}(E),\widetilde{\nabla}) = \frac{1}{2}(c^2_1(\text{End}(E)-2c_2(\text{End}(E)) = -c_2(\text{End}(E)).
$$
Also
$$
c_2(\text{End}(E)) = \frac{1}{8\pi^2}(\text{tr}(F_{\widetilde{\nabla}}^2) -\text{tr}(F_{\widetilde{\nabla}})),
$$
but for the induced connection $\widetilde{\nabla}$ on $\text{End}(E)$ we have $F_{\widetilde{\nabla}}$ so
$$
c_2(\text{End}(E)) = \frac{1}{8\pi^2}\text{tr}F_{\widetilde{\nabla}}^2.
$$
Thus
$$
\text{ch}_2(\text{End}(E),\widetilde{\nabla}) = -\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\text{tr}F_{\widetilde{\nabla}}^2.
$$
How do I get this into the form above?

I don't see what the problem is. Is $\nabla$, and hence $\tilde\nabla$, not a Chern connection? Then the curvature form will be skew-hermitian, so $F=-F^*=-\bar F{}^\top$. The only issue I can see is a factor of $1/2$. It's not clear what exactly your question is.

This factor of $1/2$ looks to be causing my trouble. Is the factor missing from the initial $$\text{ch}2(\text{End}(E),\widetilde{\nabla}) = \text{tr}\left(\frac{i}{2\pi} F{\widetilde{\nabla}} \wedge \overline{\left(\frac{i}{2\pi}F_{\widetilde{\nabla}}\right)}^T\right)$$ or am I mistakenly introducing it? @TedShifrin

There is a lot of stuff to sort out here, including the factor of $\text{rk}(E)$ that is one of the coefficients, as we saw in your previous post, of $c_2(\text{End}(E))$. Where did the formula you gave above for $c_2(\text{End}(E))$ in terms of the curvature forms come from?
